# Using IdentityServer4-the login process successfully redirects from VM2 to VM1 when we stop VM2.But, the reverse (from VM1 to VM2) does not happen

Tags: .net, azure, server, virtual-machine, identityserver4

My web application is hosted on two Virtual Machine's on Azure and I have application gateway in place on infra level. When I login in application via VM2 and after logged in, I stop the server of VM2. The user is not affected and the request redirects to VM1 and everything works fine. Now when I login via VM1, and after login when I stop the VM1 server, the user gets logged out from application forcefully and it redirects me to the log in page of application from VM2. When I entered the credentials and clicked on login button. The application keeps on loading and I get 401 status code in my api response.
I have implemented Data Protection in my application code, also I am using IdentityServer4 and I have checked the logs where it shows this error:

```
2023-05-18 09:34:14,587 [138] ERROR [IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionHandler] [Error returned from introspection endpoint: Not Found] - Error returned from introspection endpoint: Not Found
 2023-05-18 09:34:14,588 [138] INFO [IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionHandler] [BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationIntrospection was not authenticated. Failure message: Error returned from introspection endpoint: Not Found] - BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationIntrospection was not authenticated. Failure message: Error returned from introspection endpoint: Not Found
```

What could be the problem? As flow from VM2 to VM1 works fine. But reverse flow is not working.

I have printed the subjectId,email of the user from the claims inside the logs but I got null values for subjectId and email in the logs.